# iOS7 UITableView swipe to delete and touch to hide delete button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've a `UITableView` with the possibility to swipe on a cell to delete it.

I need two information

1. When a cell show the Delete button after a swipe
2. When the user tap on the screen to "close" the cell to hide the Delete button.

I need this to hide some buttons during the delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You can use this `UIableViewDelegate` method:

`tableView: willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:`

2) You can use this `UIableViewDelegate` method:

`tableView: didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath:`

Hope this help.